# Measurable body indicators for correct amount of nutrition?

Tags: nutrition, body-measurements

I can measure my general fatigue every morning by checking my resting Heart-Rate. It's shown me quite effectively, when I am a bit sick or sleep to little, my resting HR jumps up to 10 beats higher. After a resting day, I can be 3-4 beats lower than during training days.

Is there anyway to measure if I am eating/drinking enough/too little? I'm asking, since my method of consuming as I feel just allows me to indulge as an omnivore. I don't eat particularly unhealthily, nor healthily. Some numbers would be helpful to control my tendency to eat a lot "cause it tastes good" as well as sometimes to "forget to eat" during the day. Being hungry or not doesn't seem to do it for me, since hunger is somehow connected to my emotional well being lol.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm assuming you're wanting something you could do by yourself at home, and not blood work done in a lab, correct?

Comment: Yes, thats what I am looking for.

Comment: You could of course keep track of your food intake, but that's quite tedious and, if I understand your question right, not your intention, is it?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to nutrition assessment there are your ABCD's of assessing it.

- A- For **Anthropometry** involves measuring your BMI, waist circumference
  etc.
- B- For **biochemical** which you cannot readily do at home.
- C- For **clinical** features. Here you look at the color of your hands , that
  is are they reddish as an indicator of adequate iron or very pale due
  to low iron levels.

  You can look at the color of urine if it is deep yellow it means you need more water. If you eat well enough water and fiber, you should move your bowels at least once a day or else you will be constipated. You feces should clump together if there are loose it means you not eating well.
- D- is for **dietary** and you can use diet apps such as M-Diet Helper.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use one of the [food diary app's / web sites](http://appcrawlr.com/app/uberGrid/488) to log your daily calorie and nutrient intakes, for example [MyFitnessPal](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/). They all offer an estimated TDEE (total daily energy expenditure = Kcal) figure, based on your: age, weight, height and activity level. As well as suggested protein, fat, fibre, sugar, mineral, vitamin and fluid intakes. The majority have a food / calorie / nutrient database to help plan your meals.